# SQL & Website - how to optimaze website

Tags: sql, postgresql, web, orm

I want to add some statistic - how many messages user send to other users.
Now, user is going to his panel and sees that number. Should I execute

```
SELECT count(*) from MESSAGES where id=user.id
```

every user panel page is refreshed? Wouldn't it kill my DB? For exmaple 1k users refreshing account page, and in addition few pranksters who will spammingly pres F5?

I have similar problem with retrieving games played by user, last login date etc. I'm wondering is it a good idea to execute sql every time or maybe i should cache this values in local.storage and increment them every time I do update on DB value? And if user logging off then clear local storage. But in such solution local.storage can grow really big. How to solve problem if we have to deal with news or articles on blog for example?

What do you think?

Comment: Performance questions require lots of information and you provided none. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: I think in your case it would be better to store counter's value in separate field in users table. Also you need to create a triggers after insert and delete on table where you save messages and with this trigger increment or decrement statistics in that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment..

```
-- create field
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN messages_total integer;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN messages_total SET DEFAULT 0;
COMMENT ON COLUMN users.messages_total IS 'Users messages total.';

-- create trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "users_messages::update_statistics"()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        UPDATE users SET messages_total = messages_total - 1 WHERE id = OLD.user_id;
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        UPDATE users SET messages_total = messages_total + 1 WHERE id = NEW.user_id;
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 5;

CREATE TRIGGER update_statistics
  AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
  ON users_messages
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE "users_messages::update_statistics"();
```